# How to apply styles to Ionic ion-picker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I'm building an ionic app and i would like to apply some styles to an ion-picker element.
To help me illustrate what i want here is a picture of what i currently have (sorry but the content of the image is in Portuguese).

[image: My ion-picker]

First of all i need to adjust the option display so i can show the whole option text (probably showing in two lines if it is possible, or reducing the font size).

Second, i would like to have something separating the two columns.

This is my code to show the picker

```
async showFilters() {
    const columns = {
      activities: this.activities.map(obj => {
        return {text: obj.name, value: obj.id};
      }),
      districts: this.districts.map(obj => {
        return {text: obj.name, value: obj.name};
      })
    };
    columns.activities.unshift({text: 'Atividades', value: undefined});
    columns.districts.unshift({text: 'Distritos', value: undefined});
    const picker = await this.pickerController.create({
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'activity',
          options: columns.activities,
        },
        {
          name: 'district',
          options: columns.districts,
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          handler: (value) => {
            console.log(value);
          }
        }
      ],
      cssClass: 'picker',
    });
    return await picker.present();
  }
```

And this is the scss that i was testing to separate the two columns

```
.picker>ion-picker-column {
  margin-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

Is there anyway i can do what i want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
::ng-deep .picker.ion-picker-column {
   margin-left: 1px solid #eeeeee !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the scss I have used for my own picker. You must place scss for a base component in the app.scss file not the page.scss. You won't want this look but it will give you a start.

```css
//PICKER
.picker-wrapper {
    background: var(--ion-color-primary) !important; // colors the highlight
    // --border-width: 1px 0 0;
    --border-width: 0;
    --border-color: var(--ion-inactive-on-red, var(--ion-inactive-on-red, var(--ion-inactive-on-red, #ffb3b3)));
}

// Picker Toolbar and Buttons

.picker-toolbar {
    background: var(--ion-color-primary-shade) !important; //buttons
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

.picker-button {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: var(--ion-color-light) !important;
}

.picker-button {
    &:active,
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

// Picker Column

.picker-col {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    contain: content;
}

.picker-opts {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    .picker-opt {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
    }
}

.picker-above-highlight {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--ion-color-dark);
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, var(--ion-color-dark) 20%, var(--ion-color-primary) 100%) !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.picker-below-highlight {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--ion-color-dark);
    background: linear-gradient( to top, var(--ion-color-dark) 30%, var(--ion-color-primary) 100%) !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```